# How to put text in a scroll bar

Tags: html, css

[image: What it is now.]

So the txtarea on the left is what I typed in and when I put it through the Check a Api will check the availability of all the domains. But is it possible to put the **$result** in a scrollbar to?

This is the html code:

```
<body>
  <center>
    <h2>Multi domein checker</h2>
    <p>U kunt een maximum van 20 domeinnamen invoeren.</p>
    <div class="entire-thing">
    <form name="domainChecker">
    <div class="ad-left">
        <textarea rows="15" cols="18" name="domains"><?=htmlspecialchars(implode("\n", $domains))?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ad-right">
        <b><?=$result?></b>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Check"/>
    </form>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want to put text inside of the scrollbar?

Comment: Yes. You can assign fix height to 'ad-right' div and apply overflow:scroll css property

Comment: You would probably need to use a plugin to create a styleable scrollbar.  I would have to say, it's not very good ux though. (Unless you mean you want to put the result in a scrollable div - but that's completely different)

Comment: or you could use a multi-select form element. But yeah it's probably not a great UX.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki . Worked thanks!

Comment: Can you post solution as a answer so it might be helpful to anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could give a fix height to your right div and give a css "overflow-y:scroll"...

and if that doesn't solve your problem. then try creating the div itself after calling the API with the above css.